# Trying to identify mathematical symbol

Tags: notation

I encountered this symbol in an old Adobe mathematical character set, and I'm trying to identify it.  I can't find it on [Wikipedia's list of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_symbols), and it's difficult to describe it for the purposes of a Google search.

Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: And ... What now? What's your question?

Comment: I've been trying to draw it at http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html but with no luck so far.

Comment: @Gigili, my question is: what does this symbol mean?

Comment: This might help: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: It would possibly be easier if you could provide some context that you have seen this symbol in.

Comment: Perhaps some context would help?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, unfortunately I simply found the symbol in an old mathematical character set from Adobe (Universal-GreekMathWithPi).  The character set includes Greek letters and various mathematical symbols.  This was the only symbol I didn't recognize.

Comment: Maybe a fancy partial derivative?

Comment: @Channel72: "Greek" was relevant context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like `U+03D0 GREEK BETA SYMBOL`. See the [unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf) containing it.

Apparently it's just a typographical variant of $\beta$ that someone may have used for some particular purpose, like some distinguish $\phi/\varphi$, $\epsilon/\varepsilon$, $\theta/\vartheta$.

See also [this mailing list thread](http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2005-m07/0025.html). It seems to be unknown whether this symbol ever had any mathematical use.

Comment: Good eye, @Henning :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this PDF](http://store1.adobe.com/type/browser/pdfs/UNLQ/UniversalStd-GreekwMathPi.pdf), the unicode for this character is `0x3D0`, which is The Greek Beta Symbol (an alternate).

Here it is in $\LaTeX$: $\Huge\unicode{x3d0}$.

Comment: This looks like a _third_ form of beta to me. =)

Comment: @Srivatsan: $\unicode{x0392}$, $\unicode{x03B2}$, and $\unicode{x03D0}$?

Comment: Ah, it's my computer's fault. My laptop and desktop machine render the symbol in your answer differently.